# Ao escolher uma empresa conectar ao Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

Aguem poderia me ajudar estou fazendo um projeto para entregar este ano na faculdade em 4 camadas tenho uma tela login e quando digito usuário e senha escolho a empresa que devo trabalhar exemplo Empresa A, Empresa B, Empresa c, no sql server tenho 3 bancos bdEmpresaA, bdEmpresaB, bdEmpresaC, quando selecionar a empresa queria conectar ao banco correspondente mais não faço nem ideia como fazer isso segue as telas a baixo

Tela Login

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela connection string

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cadastro de empresa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu banco

```
 SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(); //Faz a conexão com o Banco de Dados
            CON.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.csSistemaEstoque; // Cria uma string de conexão
            SqlCommand CM = new SqlCommand(); //
            CM.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            CON.Open();

            CM.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbEmpresaUsuaria ([dtInclusao_emp], [razao_emp], [nomeFant_emp], [cnpj_emp], [inscEst_emp], [logradouro_emp], [endereco_emp], " +
            " [numero_emp], [compl_emp], [bairro_emp], [cidade_emp], [uf_emp], [cep_emp], [tel_emp], [tel2_emp], [email_emp], [site_emp], [endLogo_emp])" +
            " VALUES (@dtInclusao_emp, @razao_emp, @nomeFant_emp, @cnpj_emp, @inscEst_emp, @logradouro_emp, @endereco_emp, @numero_emp, " +
            " @compl_emp, @bairro_emp, @cidade_emp, @uf_emp, @cep_emp, @tel_emp, @tel2_emp, @email_emp, @site_emp, @endLogo_emp)";
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço

código na tela login

```
        private void cbbEmpresaUsuaria_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string myConnString = String.Empty;

        codEmpUsuaria = Convert.ToString(cbbEmpresaUsuaria.SelectedValue);// pego o codigo empresa usuaria selecionado no ComboBox


          var empresa = codEmpUsuaria;

          if (empresa.Equals("1"))
          {
            myConnString = "Data Source=servidor;Initial Catalog=empresaA;User ID=teste;Password=123456";

          } if (empresa.Equals("2"))
          {
                    myConnString = "Data Source=servidor;Initial Catalog=empresaB;User ID=teste;Password=123456";

          }



    }




<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Data Source=servidor;Initial Catalog=dbSistEstoqueEmp;User ID=teste;Password=123456"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Mostre o código da seleção e como você faria para uma empresa.

Comment: não entendi a sua pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai ter que mudar sua `ConnString` no evento `SelectedIndexChanged` do seu `comboBox`. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBox = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            string myConnString = String.Empty;
            if (comboBox.Equals("Empresa A"))
            {
                myConnString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NORTHWND;User ID=sa;Password=*****";
            }
            if (comboBox.Equals("Empresa B"))
            {
                myConnString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bdEmpresaB;User ID=******;Password=******";
            }
            if (comboBox.Equals("Empresa C"))
            {
                myConnString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bdEmpresaC;User ID=******;Password=******";
            }

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
            try
            {
                var SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Categories");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlA = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

                sqlA.SelectCommand = cmd;

                conn.Open();
                sqlA.Fill(tabela);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}



public partial class FormBase : Form
{
    public string myConnString
    {
        get
        {
            return "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BancoModelo;User ID=sa;Password=........";
        }
        set
        {
            myConnString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: não deu certo olha meu código coloquei na tela login atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: o que deu errado?

Comment: ele conecta sempre no mesmo banco. na pergunta esta a conection string

Comment: Então da forma que você quer, você vai ter que tira a conexão do app config e usa a que você esta criado no seu método `cbbEmpresaUsuaria_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: sou novato nisso vc poderia me dar um exemplo por favor,

Comment: alterei a resposta

Comment: Marco rachei a cuca mais parece que deu certo, deixa eu te perguntar meu projeto é 4 camadas quando chamo o frmMenu passo como parâmetro a Connection e em todas as telas que abro vou passando essa connection para a camada DAO e lá faço inclusão, consulta e alteração, é assim que é feito né. Abraço

Comment: O ideal é que você criar propriedades Gets e Sets para sua conexão e criar uma Classe Base algo assim  `FormBase : Form` e em vez de você ficar herdando a classe `Form` você herdaria sua classe `FormBase`  que já teria a sua conexão. Veja o exemplo na resposta.

Comment: entendi poderia criar uma classe com as conexões e quando escolher a conexão uso ela na aplicação com a empresa escolhida, agradeço muito pela ajuda. abraço